# Multiple Object Drag and Drop in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is there a way to implement something like icons on a desktop? Is there an easy way in Flex to implement a selection box and multiple drag and drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex supports multiple selection and multiple dnd natively.  You'll need to create your own implementation for the selection box though.

Comment: What class implements multiple section and multiple drag and drop? The DragManager class only allows one item to be dragged at a time.

Comment: List based controls that have allowMultipleSelection set to true will let you drag between them. Check out the example here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cfd.html  Run the example and select multiple entries and you'll be able to move all of the selected entries.

Comment: @WadeMueller Can we implement multiple section and multiple drag and drop on Flex canvas or borderconainer like DataGrid,
HorizontalList
,List
,PrintDataGrid
,TileList
Tree?